# Python sharing a dict with Event() variables inside it between parent and child processes

Tags: python, semaphore, python-multiprocessing

I want to share a dict with some Event() variables inside it between parent and child processes but don't know how. Notice that I need to add or delete (key, value) after the process is started. It seems that neither a normal dict nor a multiprocessing.Manager.dict like below can satisfy my requirements.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Event, Manager

manager = Manager()
d1 = manager.dict()
#  d1 = dict()

def fun():
    # do something and then set d1[1]
    time.sleep(4)
    d1[1].set()

p = Process(target=fun, name='fun')
p.start()
d1[1] = Event() # add a (key, value) after the process is defined
p.join()
print 'After fun, d1[1] = %s' % (d1[1].is_set())
```

So what is the right way to share these semaphores between parent and child processes?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
d1[1] = Event()
```

with

```
d1[1] = manager.Event()
```

Comment: It doesn't help either. I get a RemoteError message "Unserializable message: ('#RETURN', <threading._Event object at 0x108ec9790>)".

Comment: Please double check, and add `if __name__ == '__main__':` after you define `fun`

Comment: This code crashed with the same error message in my laptop. I use Python2.7 by the way.

Comment: Please send the complete traceback